How to pass argument to newcommand inside makeatletter?
In Get value of \crefname, it is shown that a variable of interest is stored in \cref@<type>@name. The accepted answer suggests using the following commands to read the variables:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\theoname}{\cref@theorem@name}
\newcommand{\Theoname}{\Cref@theorem@name}
\newcommand{\theonames}{\cref@theorem@name@plural}
\newcommand{\Theonames}{\Cref@theorem@name@plural}
\makeatother

Is it possible to provide the string that lies between the two @ signs (e.g., theorem) as an argument to these commands? For example, the ideal behavior would be
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getname}[1]{\cref@#1@name}
\makeatother

\getname{theorem} % reads \cref@theorem@name

My proposed solution does not compile.

You don't need \makeatletter to construct a name,
\newcommand{\getname}[1]{\UseName{cref@#1@name}}


Where is the \UseName command defined? I am encountering Undefined control sequence.

you must have an old latex release, you can use \newcommand{\getname}[1]{\csname cref@#1@name\endcsname} which is the same thing

@jII it was added in the 2022/06/01 latex release.
